# Javascript query fix

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am new to Javascript programming, can anyone help me on fixing the below script. In this script, I am getting some input from the user and then adding it to an array. Finally displaying it in a table. But for some reason, the last entry in the array overwrites all the previous entries in it.

```js
var CountryList = new Array();
var arrNum = 0;

function initCountry(name, capital) {
  this.name = name;
  this.capital = capital;
  //Comments
  //alert(arrNum);
  CountryList.push(this);

  document.getElementsByName("countryName")[0].value = "";
  document.getElementsByName("capitalCity")[0].value = "";
}

function funcSaveButton() {
  var txt1 = document.getElementsByName("countryName")[0];
  var txt2 = document.getElementsByName("capitalCity")[0];

  initCountry(txt1.value, txt2.value);
  //alert(txt1.value +":"+ txt2.value);
  arrNum++;
}

function displayList() {
  var i;
  document.write("<table border='2'>");
  document.write("<tr> <td> Country Name </td> <td> Capital City </td> </tr>")
  for (i = 0; i < CountryList.length; i++) {
    //alert("i="+i);
    document.write("<tr>");
    document.write("<td> " + CountryList[i].name + "</td>");
    document.write("<td> " + CountryList[i].capital + "</td>");
    document.write("</tr>");
  }
  document.write("</table>");
}
```

```html
Country Name: <input type="text" name="countryName" required></input>
<Br> Capital City: <input type="text" name="capitalCity" required></input><br><br>

<input type="button" name="saveButton" value="Save Details!!" onclick="funcSaveButton()"></input>

<input type="button" name="displayButton" value="Display Country List!!" onclick="displayList()"></input>
```

Comment: `document.write()` overwrites the entire document once it's finished loading. in short, don't use it

Comment: @SterlingArcher Sorry that is not my query here and I am aware of that as well. But the last entry to the array is overwriting the entire array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pushing window object to CountryList
inside function this object is window. 
use this `CountryList.push({name:name,capital:capital});`

```js
var CountryList = new Array();
var arrNum = 0;

function initCountry(name, capital)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.capital = capital;
    //Comments
    //alert(arrNum);
    CountryList.push({name:name,capital:capital});

    document.getElementsByName("countryName")[0].value = "";
    document.getElementsByName("capitalCity")[0].value = "";
}

function funcSaveButton()
{
    var txt1 = document.getElementsByName("countryName")[0];
    var txt2 = document.getElementsByName("capitalCity")[0];

    initCountry(txt1.value, txt2.value);
    //alert(txt1.value +":"+ txt2.value);
    arrNum++;   
}

function displayList()
{   
console.log(CountryList);

    var i;
    document.write("<table border='2'>");
    document.write("<tr> <td> Country Name </td> <td> Capital City </td> </tr>")
    for(i=0;i<CountryList.length;i++)
    {       
        //alert("i="+i);
        document.write("<tr>");
        document.write("<td> "+ CountryList[i].name + "</td>");
        document.write("<td> "+ CountryList[i].capital + "</td>");
        document.write("</tr>");
    }
    document.write("</table>");
}
```

```html
Country Name: <input type="text" name="countryName" required></input><Br>
Capital City: <input type="text" name="capitalCity" required></input><br><br>

<input type="button" name="saveButton" value="Save Details!!" onclick="funcSaveButton()"></input>

<input type="button" name="displayButton" value="Display Country List!!" onclick="displayList()"></input>
```